# Programmatically opening a Leaflet popup if its coordinates match map.getCenter(), or if it meets some other condition?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

How can we make Leaflet open specific markers' popups if they meet some condition? We want to write something that if any marker's location matches `map.getCenter()` then something should trigger `.openPopup()`, but we don't know how to trigger `.openPopup()` or otherwise set something that'll make the popup / tooltip open.

We've found `onEachFeature` in [Leaflet's docs](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) and have coded it to identify the condition we want, but we don't know how set `.openPopup()` from there, as `feature.openPopup();` doesn't work. Can opening the popup be enabled from within `onEachFeature`, or are we approaching this in the wrong way?

Reproducible eg of what we have with console logging when condition is met:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    html,body {margin: 0px;height: 100%;}
    body {display: flex;}
</style>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>

    <div id="mapid" style="flex: 1"></div>
    <script>var myMap = L.map("mapid");
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(myMap);
        myMap.setView([20.2, -87.46], 11);

        var geojsonFeatureCollection =
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-87.8, 20.2]
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "prop0": "non auto pop up text",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-87.46, 20.2]
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "prop0": "auto pop up text",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.geometry.coordinates[1].toFixed(5) == myMap.getCenter().lat.toFixed(5) &&
                feature.geometry.coordinates[0].toFixed(5) == myMap.getCenter().lng.toFixed(5)) 
            {console.log('something to make pop up open should happen here')}
        }

        L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, coordinates) {
                return L.marker(coordinates);
            }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        })
            .bindPopup((layer) => layer.feature.properties.prop0)
            .addTo(myMap)
            ;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note we don't want to open markers' popups through conditions found in the `geojsonFeatureCollection` because of reasons we don't want to unnecessarily complicate this question with. We only want a marker's popup to open if some condition found elsewhere is met, and for popups to then function normally. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to open the popup before it is added to the map.

So a solution is to bind the popup in the `onEachFeature` function and then open the popup when the layer is added to the map:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup((layer) => layer.feature.properties.prop0)

    if (feature.geometry.coordinates[1].toFixed(5) == myMap.getCenter().lat.toFixed(5) &&
        feature.geometry.coordinates[0].toFixed(5) == myMap.getCenter().lng.toFixed(5))
    {
        layer.once('add',()=>{
            layer.openPopup();
        })
    }
}

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, coordinates) {
        return L.marker(coordinates);
    }, 
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(myMap);
```